# Creating a global service for an AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service through which I am doing access control in every part of my app.

Currently, I am having a lot of controllers and consequently I have a very tedious task of having to inject the service manually in each controller.

**Is there any way of injecting the service to each controller programmatically?** I only have a single module and I am using **ui-router**(if I can use it)

Comment: Good One. but got to think about it. until now keep injecting it manually.

Comment: Can't you inject the service once in a parent controller, listen for events (like routeChanges, etc) that require access validation and then check access permissions?

Comment: Access permissions aren't just for states and not generic either. It would be to messy.

Comment: Route resolver is the de facto solution for managing access permissions. Anything else would be messy. If the access to particular controller isn't handled by the state, then it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.run(function (globalService, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.globalService = globalService;
});
```

and `$scope.$root.globalService` in controller.

It can be `angular.globalService = globalService`. Or `window.globalService = globalService`.

As a form of global variable, each of them effectively nullifies the benefits of dependency injection and can't be considered a recommended practice.